# Presenting login UINavigationController shows black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

My iOS app requires user authentication, and when the user is not authenticated, the app should displayed a ViewController where the user can login. This screen also gives users the option to create an account, so the whole login screens (and optional registration screens) are setup using a UINavigationController that is displayed programatically.

The login screen is displayed with the following code:

```
- (void)promptCredentials{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *loginScreenNav = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginNavigationController"];
        [loginScreenNav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
        [self presentModalViewController:loginScreenNav animated:YES];
    });
}
```

However, when this method is called, the app navigates to a black screen [image]. What is the correct way to present the user with a different ViewController programatically? I have found several SO questions related to such black screens, however, none of the answers have worked for me. My app is running on iOS 8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a UIViewcontroller and set that as the rootController for your UINAvigationController.

presentModalViewController is deprecated as of ios6, try using presentViewController.

```
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginNavigationController"];

UINavigationController  *loginScreenNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self presentViewController:loginScreenNav animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your code fails with the following exception: Pushing a navigation controller is not supported

Comment: Does your current VC have a navigation controller already?  If so, don't create a new nav controller, simply push the Vc.. [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

Comment: If I just present the vc, then I simply get a black screen (without the blue navigation bar as per the screenshot above, as this is provided by the navigation controller)

Comment: Have you stepped through it, how's your storyboard look? Are you sure you have stuff in "LoginNavigationController" that should show.. If you want to share your project I'll take a quick look.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo when I copied and edited the code you shared. The problem is resolved now, thanks a mil!